# Django using another templating engine (Chameleon)

Tags: django, template-engine

I wonder if i can use another templating engine besides django's on django project, to be exact, it's [chameleon](http://chameleon.repoze.org/), and there are any performance issues? Just curious, because i'm more familiar with `chameleon`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easier part to replace in Django is the template engine, and it is not famous for the astonishing performance.

I'm pleased with the results from mixing [Django and Jinja2](http://matthowell.com/blog/2011/03/02/integrating-jinja2-and-django/), unfortunately I can't comment on chamaleon.